# Big O and little O notation examples

Tags: number-theory

I'm reading the book "An introduction to the theory of numbers, sixth edition" by Hardy and Wright.

On page 8 they describe three notations with examples,

---

(1) $f = O(\phi)$ means that $|f| < A\phi$

(2) $f = o(\phi)$ means that $f/g \rightarrow 0 $

(3) $f \sim \phi$ means that $f/g \rightarrow 1$

Thus

$$10x = O(x), \sin x = O(1), x = O(x^2)\\
x = o(x^2), \sin x = o(x), x + 1 \sim x,$$

where $x \rightarrow \infty $, and

$$ x^2 = O(x), x^2 = o(x), \sin x \sim x, 1 + x \sim 1,$$

when $x \rightarrow 0$.

---

My question is about $x + 1 \sim x$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. Wouldn't you get $\frac{\infty + 1}{\infty} = undefined$ as opposed to 1 as the author states?

Comment: To write $x \sim x+1$, it means that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{x + 1} = 1$$ This is easily seen after noting that $$\frac{x}{x + 1} = \frac{1}{1 + 1/x}$$ Now letting $x \to \infty$, we get $1 / (1 + 0) = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This notation is about limits and not literally plugging in $\infty$ to see what you get. If you plug in $\infty$ then you would get the same indeterminate answer for $x^2$ vs. $x$ as you did for $x+1$ vs. $x$. For $x + 1$ vs. $x$, note that you get

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x+1}{x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} 1 + 1/x = 1$$

so indeed $x + 1 \sim x$.